# Can anyone describe the step by step process of recovery , backup and restore in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone  describe the step by step process of recovery via backup and restore in SQL Server 2008.

If possible please include some examples.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the links:

1.Backup Under the Full Recovery Model

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190217%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx

2.BACKUP and RESTORE Commands

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848768

3.Back Up and Restore of SQL Server Databases

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

When the database is restored the pages are read from the backup file and written to the correct location in the new physical database file.  Any transactions which were within the transaction log are then read from the backup file and applied to the database file or rolled back.  When that is done the database is either brought online or left offline so that other backups can be restored.

When backups are taken the same process is used.  All the pages which are within the database file are written to the backup file.  Any transactions within the transaction log are then backed up into the file as well.

Comment: Thanks mrdenny.Can  you please explain with  a simple example ?

Comment: That was the simple example.  The only other basic information is that you use the BACKUP DATABASE and RESTORE DATABASE statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this video:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9U7QxPsA0tw&feature=related - Backup & Restore Step-By-Step part 1

Hope it will help